# How to display Button text after a delay in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-animation

I created new custom `Button` class, I want to achieve, whenever user go to any activity my generic button want to expand from circle to default width. While expanding I want to hide button text for while until button animation complete.

**Please check my below code:**

```
 private void animateMe(Context context){
    final String btnText = this.getText().toString();
    final FIButton fiButton = this;
    fiButton.setText("");

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            fiButton.setText(btnText);
        }

    },500);


    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
            R.anim.expand);
    super.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easily by

```
ViewCompat.animate(fiButton ).setStartDelay(500).alpha(1).setDuration(700).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(1.2f)).start();
```

note that you have to set the fiButton alpha to zero                 `android:alpha="0.0"`
in you xml or on create view

this line will animate your view from 0 to 1 in 700 millisecond after 500 millisecond.

Comment: i find another way to achieve this animation effect by using Circular Reveal by material design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `AnimationListener`. On finishing the animation you should do `setText` on the `TextView`.

```
private void animateMe(Context context){
    final String btnText = this.getText().toString();
    final FIButton fiButton = this;

    fiButton.setText("");        
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.expand);        
    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            fiButton.setText("");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            fiButton.setText(btnText);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    super.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

Comment: And i have another issue, as i mentioned i want to transform all the buttons from circle state to wrap_content width.. all my buttons have border radius. when i animate its shows in square.
`<scale
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromXScale="0.1"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale=".9"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="100%" />`